# Why is the victory/defeat screen sometimes in color and sometimes desaturated?

Tags: hearthstone

Sometimes the victory/defeat screen has the game board behind it in full color:

[image: Full color Victory! screeen]
[image: Full color Defeat! screen]

Sometimes the game board is desaturated, almost but not quite grayscale:

[image: Desaturated Victory! screen]
[image: Desaturated Defeat! screen]

(All screenshots are from playing a Tavern Brawl on the Android version of Hearthstone; the fourth is from a phone instead of a tablet hence the layout variation, but this doesn't seem to account for the difference.)

What's the logic behind this?

Disproven hypotheses:

- It can't be exclusively whether you won or lost; as illustrated above all four combinations are possible.
- It can't be exclusively "gray if you get a 10 gold reward", because the fourth screenshot contradicts that.
- It can't depend on the battlefield theme because all four above are the same one.
- It can't be "gray if you got any kind of reward", because I've gotten quest rewards with a colorful screen (in Casual) and been defeated with no rewards with a gray screen (in Arena).

Comment: hmmm that's interesting. the only difference I see is that the grey versions gave you a reward (gold) EDIT: nevermind the 4th is a defeat screen...

Comment: Ok. I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like if you get a reward (10G from 3 wins, quests completed, card from leveling up, ...) then the background will be grey At least that's what i noticed yesterday.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW It can't be exactly that, because I just got a quest reward with a colorful background.

Comment: Another THEORY: the color changes after you finished a game you reconnected to after losing the connection.

Comment: I think it's completely random but have no evidence for this

Comment: Hearthstone has had defects in the past where losing focus (so tabbing away or click on another window on your computer) can cause graphics changes.

Comment: Another possibility is that its tied to any visual effects from cards happening on the board when the game ended, but thats just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have conducted a small experiment.
Over the last two weeks (I do play quite heavily) I have won 154 games.

54% of these I have had a colourless win-screen.
The rest of these (46% have had coloured win screens).

There are no apparant factors which effect the colour..

Comment: "There seems to be no factors" may be better worded as "There are no apparent factors." There are definitely some inputs that are causing this output (video games are deterministic after all), they're just not **apparent**.

Comment: Thanks @scohe001 I've reworded my answer.